# How to show a Chromecast introduction screen?

Tags: java, android, audio, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am developing an audio app for Android with Java as the language.
The guide from Google says

A   Show a Cast introduction screen the first time Web Receivers are available
B   Visually highlight the cast button (e.g. circle the button)
C   Explain how the cast button works (e.g. "Touch to cast videos to your TV")

I have searched the available sample code and tutorials, but I don't find any example code for this in Java. So how do I show a Chromecast introduction screen?

Answer (score 0):

This very convenient interface is now available from Google:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/IntroductoryOverlay

It was very easy to implement what I wanted with this!